# Нефиксированная длина набора символов

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте. Проблема в следующем.

Вводятся данные в **edit1** и **edit2**, данные заносятся в текстовой файл. После, происходит так называемая "авторизация", где в поля **edit1(2)** нужно ввести данные из записанных ранее в текстовой файл. Но вот в чем проблема: *edit'ы воспринимают только 5 символов и, если данные из текстового файла будут больше или меньше 5 символов, то программа ничего не делает.* Что можно в таком случае сделать?

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Edit4: TEdit;
    Label5: TLabel;
    Edit5: TEdit;
    Label6: TLabel;
    Edit6: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;
   f:textfile;
implementation

uses Unit2, Unit4;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var s:string;
begin
if  (edit1.Text='') or  (edit2.Text='') or (edit3.Text='') or (edit4.Text='') or (edit5.Text='')  or (edit6.Text='')  then
ShowMessage ('Шеф, всё пропало!')
else
begin
AssignFile(f, 'a.txt');
Reset(f);  // открыть файл
  append(f);  // добавление в файл
s:=edit1.Text+' '+edit2.Text+' '+edit3.Text+' '+edit4.Text+' Логин '+edit5.Text+' Пароль '+edit6.Text;
   writeln(f,s);
   CloseFile(f); // закрыть файл
Form3.close;
Form2.Visible:=True;
end;
edit1.Text:='';
edit2.Text:='';
edit3.Text:='';
edit4.Text:='';
edit5.Text:='';
edit6.Text:='';
end;

procedure TForm3.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

Form3.close;
Form2.Visible:=True;
edit1.Text:='';
edit2.Text:='';
edit3.Text:='';
edit4.Text:='';
edit5.Text:='';
edit6.Text:='';
end;

end.
```

2:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
   f:textfile;
implementation

uses Unit2, Unit4, Unit8;

{$R *.dfm}
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
pos1:integer;                                                                  
pos2:integer;                                                   
a:boolean;
s,s1:string;
s2:string;
begin
   a:=false;
 If   (edit1.Text='Admin') or  (edit2.Text='Admin')   then
  begin
  Form1.Visible:=false;
  edit1.Text:='';
  edit2.Text:=''; 
  Form8.Visible:=true;
 end
 else
 begin

 if  (edit1.Text='') or  (edit2.Text='')   then
  ShowMessage ('Неправильный логин или пароль!')
 else
  begin
   AssignFile(f, 'a.txt');
   Reset(f);  // открыть файл
   while not Eof(f) do
    begin
     //Читаем очередную строку файла в переменную S
     Readln(f, S);
     pos1:=pos('Логин ',s);
     pos2:=pos('Пароль ',s);
     s1:=copy(s,pos1+6,5 );
     s2:=copy(s,pos2+7,5) ;
     if (edit1.Text=s1) and  (edit2.Text=s2)   then a:=true;
    end;
    CloseFile(f);
    if a then
     begin
       Form1.Visible:=False;
       edit1.Text:='';
       edit2.Text:='';
       Form4.Visible:=true;
     end;
  end;
 end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

Form1.Visible:=false;
Form2.Visible:=True;
edit1.Text:='';
edit2.Text:='';
end;
```

Comment: Очень порадовала комбинация

Reset(f);  // открыть файл
  append(f);  // добавление в файл

Comment: Подумал про доту (... лина символов ...) когда прочёл, пора бросать.

Comment: @all: нужен новый тег "простыня".

Answer (score 2):

```
 s1:=copy(s,pos1+6,5 );
 s2:=copy(s,pos2+7,5) ;
```

Вас не смутила цифра 5 и кол-во копируемых символов?

Comment: В корень зришь... Действительно почему только 5ть символов копируется, не больше или не меньше :-)